# Attach event handler to KendoUI widget (View)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am attempting to work an existing web app to use Kendo (Mobile) UI widgets.
All of the existing javascript code base is contained within AMD modules (RequireJS).

I would like to attach a 'show' event handler to a view, so that the app can request data from the back end, however the data logic is within a module, and cannot be called from the page script (and thus, I can't use Kendo data`-event` attributes).

I thought that I would be able to to attach an event handler in code like so:

```
$('#tabstrip-browse').on("show", function(e) {...});
```

however, the event handler is not called.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems I'm finally able to answer my own question

My issue was that I was trying to use jQuery event binding syntax to bind to the events, however, [KendoUI does not expose events in a jQuery friendly/compliant way](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/general-discussions/binding-to-widget-events.aspx#lq2WKOPrG0eGLQukdAwt3A).

However, there is a way to do this [using the KendoUI API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/basics/events-and-methods#bind-to-the-widget-events)

Comment: This syntax doesn't work on a Kendo ComboBox (V. 2014.1.415):   $("#cb").data("kendoComboBox").bind("select", function(){ ...  });

Comment: @Misi - looking at the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#events-change) that _should_ work. 
Maybe check that each of your chained calls are returning the expected items

Comment: Still can't do this on Kendo Mobile View :(

Comment: I am still not able to do with Kendo Mobile View, how ever in my use case there was an option to use on change event as it was binded with input type text.

Comment: @ThilakRao  think I have heard and seen your name somewhere.

Comment: Can we use data-after-show event in kendo observables?

Comment: @jaydeepmarvaniya I don't use Kendo UI anymore. Their APIs might have changed. Looks like you work with my former employer.

Comment: @ThilakRao  yes that's true:-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard 'show' event in javascript or jQuery. You can bind custom events, but you need to also include a way to trigger them.

Here's a trivial example:

```
// bind the custom event    
$('#element').on('show', function(e) {
  // handle the custom event
});

// trigger the custom event
$('#element').trigger('show');
```

Comment: the question was specifically about KendoUI - it seems that Kendo does not expose a public 'show' event (tho it is accessible via it's 'unobtrusive' attributes)... I'm not sure you've understood the question

Comment: Seems to me you're asking how to bind a non-standard event to a view. That's not Kendo specific. Are you asking how to expose it through a view-model and bind it using Kendo? Are you using Durandal? You don't give enough information.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attach event on Durandal
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/UQ9hXpwP_ds

Comment: I can't see anything in the supplied link which explains attaching to a KendoUI **event**

Comment: There is the attached event, where the data logic maybe requested and bound to the datasource.